# Alembic ImportError: No module named config

Tags: python, virtualenv, alembic

Alembic was working great for me, running in a python virtual environment.

Then a couple hours ago I started getting this error when I run any alembic command and I have no explanation.

```
~/Desktop/cs/montage_web $ alembic upgrade head
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/maxfowler/Dropbox/desktop/cs/virtualenvs/mweb/bin/alembic", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('alembic==0.8.5', 'console_scripts', 'alembic')()
  File "/Users/maxfowler/Dropbox/desktop/cs/virtualenvs/mweb/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 474, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/Users/maxfowler/Dropbox/desktop/cs/virtualenvs/mweb/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2582, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/Users/maxfowler/Dropbox/desktop/cs/virtualenvs/mweb/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2265, in load
    return self._load()
  File "/Users/maxfowler/Dropbox/desktop/cs/virtualenvs/mweb/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2268, in _load
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
ImportError: No module named config
```

Answer (score 33):

finally found the answer:

I had accidentally added an __init__.py file to my alembic directory in my repository which messed everything up (presumably this made my alembic code folder be discovered before the alembic python package, thus causing things to go awry).

Comment: Thank You! You saved me several hours of debugging probably <3

Comment: but i dont have __init_.py file in alembic directory